# Is the NuGet Package Manager "Last Updated" field wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I really hope this is a duplicate and that the issue is not just me. When I open the NuGet Package Manager in VS 2012, the "Last Updated" field is always showing today's date for every package in the official online gallery. I know this isn't right because it's showing that for my own packages which I haven't updated in weeks.

Is this a bug in the package explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: i tried 2.2 from nuget ci server ci.nuget.org and looks like this has been fixed for the upcoming 2.2 release

It seems to be duplicate of http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2173 ...

Comment: You may be right, I was unsure because this was reported in May, and I only recall experiencing this in the last few weeks.

Comment: actually I see now this has been fixed for the upcoming 2.2 release

Comment: Downloaded version 2.2.31210.9045 today, and it looks fixed. The field name changed from "Last Updated" to "Last Published".